# How to replicate one ubuntu system to other ubuntu system as it is

Tags: 12.10, system-installation, iso

In my system I have installed ubuntu 12.10 (consider as system A). Also I have set up another system with ruby and some other system configuration like important drivers and all the other api that required for me. (consider I have set up one ruby project in my ubuntu system).

Now I have another ubuntu 12.10 (System B) system. I want to copy or get whole set up of system A to the system B so that I don't required to re-set up my B system.

Is there any way that I can get one system setup to the another system (Replicate the system) as it is?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you can get both hard drives onto the same computer, it would be easy.  But in any case, you can make an exact copy, but the method depends on how you want to transfer it.  A big enough USB drive would work, but would take a lot longer. There's probably a way to do it over the network, but I've never done it that way, so I can't say for sure what would be the best way.

Comment: 12.10 expired in April 2014. So you will not be able to update it. But user settings are in /home which is most of your configuration. If you changed some hardware settings they are in /etc, but only if exactly the same system version might I copy any /etc files to new system. I would manually review to see if needed if an update. And I would extract a list of installed apps and install those in new system. If your Ruby or any server type apps like database or web server, have created folders in / somewhere those would also have to be copied.

Comment: What exactly is the setup that you want to copy? Changes to /etc config? Packages that you have installed? Your /home/user directory?

Answer (score 2):

It seems what you're looking for is a **Cloning** solution, and I can recommend [**Clonezilla**](http://clonezilla.org/) for this.

You can create a **Clonezilla Live USB**, save your system partition(s) and then restore onto another computer, where the target partition(s) should be no smaller than the source partition(s).

As a result, you will have an exact replicate of your system. The only exception will be any references / symlinks to other partitions, including the swap partition in fstab, which you can easily edit and replace with the UUIDs of such partitions on the second disk.

[image]